# Why is Bernie Sanders maximum accepted donation on actblue $5600?

Tags: united-states, campaign-finance, funding

Check [here](https://secure.actblue.com/donate/bern-launch-social?refcode=tw190219-description) and try to enter a number higher than $5600.

I know this question might be oddly specific, but i have no idea why it would be such an odd number, and not just $5000.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The FEC raised [contribution limits](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/candidate-taking-receipts/contribution-limits/) for the 2020 election cycle to $2,800 for each election period. The primary and general election each counts separately, so for both of those elections the maximum individual contribution someone can give to a single candidate adds up to $5,600. See also [this announcement](https://www.opensecrets.org/news/2019/02/fec-raises-contribution-limits-for-2020-cycle/) from OpenSecrets.org.

Comment: Thanks, american elections sure are confusing - does this number change for every new election? I really wonder what its based on - demographics on the financial situation of the voters perhaps

Comment: @FlyingThunder Governing authority is FEC according to [Federal Election Campaign Act of 1971](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Election_Campaign_Act) (as amended in 1974, which is when the FEC was created). It was [amended again](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/STATUTE-116/pdf/STATUTE-116-Pg81.pdf) in 2002 to set 2001 as a base year (replacing 1974) for which to determine inflation-adjusted increases to the limits, with those increases occurring in odd numbered years. (See Page 23 of previous link)

Comment: @FlyingThunder The concept of any part of American politics giving a rat's ass for the financial situation of the voters is... utterly laughable.

Comment: @FlyingThunder In general, if a number is odd, it started as a round number and keeps getting inflation adjusted, for which the [consumer price index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_price_index) is the US standard. Examples: tax brackets, people's salaries, retirement benefits, etc. I don't think this is specific to the US.

Comment: So you can contribute to someone's general election campaign before you know whether they'll win the primary and *have* a general election campaign?

Comment: @PeterTaylor [This comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38905/why-is-bernie-sanders-maximum-accepted-donation-on-actblue-5600#comment149695_38908) says that money donated to the general election campaign has to be returned if that campaign doesn't happen.

Answer (score 23):

Because that's the legal limit. You can give $2,800 per election, so $5,600 would be a combined primary/general limit.

https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/candidate-taking-receipts/contribution-limits/

Comment: what happens to the second $2800 if the candidate isn't selected?

Comment: @JCRM https://www.investopedia.com/articles/markets/042716/what-happens-campaign-funds-after-elections.asp - "According to the FEC rules, official candidate committees must return any money contributed towards the general election if they do not win the primaries."

Comment: @RamonSnir Is it *if they do not win the primaries*, or *if they do not enter the general election*? Could they keep the money if they choose to run as an independent? (This is an unusual enough scenario that I'm not sure I trust the phrasing at these links to be accurate for it)

Comment: If they run as an independent, then they're in the general election, they can keep the money, what's the issue?

Comment: @Draco18s: The issue is that the text Ramon quoted from Investopedia says differently.

Comment: @BenVoigt Here are the exact procedures. https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/candidate-taking-receipts/remedying-excessive-contribution/