# Why does the Biden campaign have a $32 donation tier?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, campaign-finance, joe-biden

Going onto the [Joe Biden website](https://joebiden.com/), it's currently asking for donations for his presidential election campaign and potential legal action. Some of the options seem to be quite random though:

[image]

<sup>*For those who can't see the image, the options are $15, $32, $50, $100, $250, $500, $2800, and OTHER.*</sup>

Most of these are nice round numbers which is understandable. Looking at [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/38905/34896), the $2800 is due to being the maximum contribution that an individual can make. But why $32? Is there a reason for this not being a round number like the rest?

Comment: My guess for the reason is that the average of 15 and 50 is 32.5 which was rounded down.

Comment: Perhaps this was the average donation amount he received when the donation options were created.

Comment: Huh? It's actually the *only* round number in the list </binary mode>

Comment: I'm with @Glorfindel on this one. All of the other numbers look off to me. [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/oddlyspecific/comments/i95e83/32_just_seems_like_an_oddly_specific_donation/) from two months ago doesn't look like they got to the bottom of it.

Comment: It makes sense to me. The original amounts might have been 16, 32, 64, 128, 512, 1024 and 2800.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire ahh that would make sense. I was thinking too much of the political answer, and ignoring common sense. Maybe I should become a politician...

Comment: @Glorfindel touché!

Comment: This seems like more of a UX question (you might ask on that stack in fact).  I would wager that this is taking advantage of the fact that people prefer to use one of the pre-defined options, prefer not to pick the cheapest option, and usually tend to land on the second-cheapest option.  If they add $2 to the "natural" $30 option, they get 6.67% more money from everyone that chooses the second cheapest option (simliar to the "second cheapest wine effect").

Comment: @Glorfindel Well, of course it was probably rounded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The addition of the $32 option was made on 28 July 2020 ([archive 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200728082849/joebiden.com), [archive 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200728213252/joebiden.com)).

The average donation around that time was also $32, shown by [this promotional email sent](https://milled.com/joe-biden-2020/why-im-asking-for-5-gO8B7Zgsd111bNgm), which quotes that figure for April, and [this Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/joebiden/posts/can-i-tell-you-something-im-proud-of-when-we-started-this-campaign-our-average-d/10157292342186104/), which was posted on the 6th of August, just a few days after the addition of the option, which repeats that figure.

Considering this, I think that it is reasonable to assume Biden added the $32 donation option because it was the average donation at the time -- rounded, of course, for simplicity.

Comment: All makes complete sense, thanks! I was assuming it was going to be like the charity adverts you see on TV, "donate £X and you can fund a vaccine/water/school for 10 people" type of thing, and was wondering what $32 could buy in a presidential election!

Comment: @crazyloonybin No problem! Glad you found the answer helpful!

Comment: If true, that's very smart.  I wonder if they made it $33 instead of $32, if they would have eked out another $1 from donors or if fewer people would have contributed.  Said another way, I wonder if their revenue would have increased or decreased if they had chosen $33 instead of $32.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a "stretch" tier. [Obama small donors in 2008 often gave less than $25](https://www.politico.com/story/2008/05/obamas-army-of-small-donors-010223)

> Dozens of Associated Press interviews with donors and an AP financial analysis show how contributions that make only a soft ka-ching by themselves, arriving in increments of $10, $15 and $50, have collectively swelled into a financial roar that has helped propel Obama toward the Democratic presidential nomination.

And

> Ninety percent of his donors give $100 or less, and 41 percent have given $25 or less, according to the Obama campaign. Overall, he has raised 45 percent of his money in small contributions.

$32 is about 2/3 of $50, and only $7 more than the logical $25 tier. And in 2016 [Bernie Sanders said his average was $27](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/04/18/bernie-sanders-keeps-saying-his-average-donation-is-27-but-it-really-isnt/) (actual numbers vary somewhat)

> And yet, Sanders still regularly mentions the same stat: His average donation is $27.

Sanders had a $27 tier on his website instead of a $25 tier. As such, this is likely an attempt by the Biden campaign to convince Sanders donors (and others) to contribute more by skipping the $25 tier. [The average Biden contribution was $44](https://www.npr.org/2020/10/14/923851384/biden-announces-record-383-million-september-haul)

Comment: Interesting to see the uplift from $32 average in May to $44 In October across the two answers here. Though there is probably no way to know how the introduction of the $32 donation teir affected that.

Comment: Thanks for the information, makes sense what you've said skipping the $25 option to try and gain a bit extra. Chosen the other answer as accepted, because they found a Joe Biden email stating the average donation was $32 which seems the likely reason why that exact figure was chosen, but thanks for the info and useful links!